# Run a script when I put a pendrive in

Tags: linux, ubuntu, backup

I want to have automatic backup of some directories on my pendrive whenever I insert a pendrive to my laptop running Ubuntu 10.04. What whould be the simplest solution for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either write a [udev rule](http://reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html) to run the script, or write a D-Bus client that [listens to hal](http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/hal/2005-January/001623.html).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on Linux, but for Windows I have seen an autorun file added that references a batch file to do the job. Worked exactly as you described!